# Let a thread sleep, or run on a Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I answered a post with a threading question that was down voted a number of times, but now it's got me second guessing an already in place solution that has been running for years. If I have some work that needs to be done often but not always like processing elements in a queue. Is it better to let a thread sleep when not working or to start a task every time an element needs to be processed. Based upon research around lifetime of the thread which would be the length of the application run it seemed that creating a new thread is the better choice. Is the Task solution better than the other? If you have another version that you think is better than both for the problem feel free to submit.

```
class DoSomething
{
  public void Enqueue(object item)
  {
    Task.Run(() => ProcessItem(item));
  }

  public void ProcessItem(object item)
  {
    //Do some work here that needs to be async from submission
  }
}

class DoSomething2
{
  public DoSomething2()
  {
    _t = new Thread(ProcessItem) { IsBackground = true };
    _t.Start();
  }
  private Thread _t;
  private ConcurrentQueue<object> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue <object>();

  public void Enqueue(object item)
  {
    _queue.Enqueue(item);
  }

  public void ProcessItem(object item)
  {

    while (true)
    {
      while (_queue.Count > 0)
      {
        //Dequeue here and do some work here that needs to be async from submission
      }
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
  }
}
```

Edit 1. Since people have asked I wanted to give some more information about it. This class is a mock up of a logging class that I created to centralize events for a set of distributed services. Some which have many events on the order of millions and some which have maybe a few hundred over the course of the day. Is there one solution that is optimal for both. My concern with Tasks is that the overhead of creating millions of task objects would outweigh the fire and forget benefit.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You can start the task on it's own thread and give it a low priority and it will run when nothing else is happening, however I don't know what the advantage would be to making it sleep. What are you actually trying to do? Also note that if a higher priority task is occupying all the resources, the low priority task might never run.

Comment: These are two completely different solutions. One is not *better* than the other in general; only for specific scenarios. For example, can these tasks be run independently? Your first solution assumes that is the case but the second does not.

Comment: @mikez You don't need to create a thread that runs continuously just to synchronize a series of operations.  So yes, it's true that one implementation synchronizes the operations and one doesn't, that's not inherent to the idea of having dedicated thread(s) created to process the items versus doing the work asynchronously or using the thread pool.  You can have either synchronize the operations or either parallelize them.

Comment: @Servy Sure. I was only pointing out a substantive difference in behavior between the options; not that they were the best or only way to achieve those outcomes.

Comment: @mikez there is no requirement for synchronization. The reason for a concurrent queue is used is to avoid issues when the internal index is jumping around as the array grows or shrinks. There is no requirement that it be processed in order, just that it eventually is. I think for small cases the Task approach is probably better, but for my situation I don't want to maintain two different implementations. I would if there was evidence that one was significantly better than the other in a situation, but seems like the jury is out still.